# How do p2p clients exchange files directly?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, p2p

Apologies in advance for not knowing the proper terminology.

I was wondering how p2p (e.g. BitTorrent) clients exchange a file directly.

My computer is behind a router. It has no public IP and therefore no one is able to connect to it from the outside of its local network.

My current understanding is that there should be a computer with a publicly accessible IP to serve the peers. But the whole point of peer-to-peer protocols is to allow direct communication between two peers.

How is that done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router has its own public IP that it uses when talking to the outside world.  If it did not, there would be no point to your question, since you would only be able to transfer data with other computers within your private network, you would have no Internet connection, etc.

What you are looking for is called [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal).  It is what allows peer-to-peer connections through routers and other NAT (Network Address Translation) devices.

Comment: Thanks! So, do torrent clients/peers use NAT traversal techniques to connect to each other?

Comment: All peer-to-peer apps have to employ NAT traversal techniques if they want to pass data through NATs without requiring user intervention to configure the NATs.